# get help of specific command's option

Tags: man

Without using `man` and in a single command from `--help`, I'd like to know further information for certain options. I know that for every command, by default the option `-h` or `--help` will print a help page with a list of available options. But how can I get *only* the description of a particular option?

In the web and here in particular we see a lot of instructions and commands and I'd like to read more about it without searching in the full list.

For example, I know that `rsync -h` means

```
-h, --human-readable        output numbers in a human-readable format
```

or that `ls -l` means

```
-l                         use a long listing format
```

How to get that specific information in a short command?

Comment: `rsync --help | grep '\-l,'`

Comment: @jasonwryan `grep -- -l` seems easier to me.

Comment: @jasonwryan thanks a lot, this question is different from the allegedly "duplicate" but your solution is simple and perfect.